# disable scroll on iPad, but still be able to use input type=range slider

Tags: ipad, slider, preventdefault

I'm interested in a CSS approach to disabling scrolling on the iPad.  I'm using an input type of range to create a slider, but would like to prevent scrolling on the rest of the iPad to keep a fixed position of the body.

Does anyone have a foolproof method?

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot...but nobody else answered this either.  HERE IS THE ANSWER:

1. create a slider with the input type="range" and give it an id
2. add the following code to the page:

   ```
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {if(e.target.id != 'slider_id'){e.preventDefault(); }}, false);
   ```